# How can I find what version of an npm module is used across github repo?

Tags: github, npm, versioning, github-search

I have an npm module I develop. I want to know which version of this module is being used across the different projects in my company's organization repository. Is there a way to run a search for a specific versions of a module?

For example my latest version of the module is `"5.x.x"`. I want to find all usages that are not `"^5.x.x"`.

I tried searching for `filename:package.json my-module` but this gives me too many results, which most of them is the latest version (`"^5.x.x"`).

Maybe there is some other way to achieve it which is not the Github search?

**Edit**:

- The organization repository is huge and it is impossible to have it all cloned on the disk.
- In our organization we have a solution that solves this problem using coding (a service that manages all dependencies across the organization which exposes REST). I am looking for something that can be achieved easily without coding (too much).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` and `grep` commands in Bash:

```
$ cd path/to/your/repo
$ find . -name package.json | xargs grep '"my_module":'
```

This command lists all lines with your module in all package.json files across the repository. If this yields too many results, you can `grep` some more, for example:

```
$ find . -name package.json | xargs grep '"my_module":' | grep -v '\^5\.'
```

which excludes any lines mentioning your module with major version number of 5.

Comment: I'm guessing the search needs to be across all repos in an org, on GitHub, without cloning.

Comment: In that case, maybe using github search API to get all the package.json URLs, download these into a folder and do a grep over these files..

Comment: The `find` command here will end up grabbing all the `package.json` files of subdependencies. That's not necessarily a bad thing although it could greatly slow the command. It's not what the OP is doing in the question, where they're searching just `package.json` in the project itself on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Given the [restrictions placed on GitHub search](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-code#considerations-for-code-search), it's unlikely you'll be able to easily do this in the GitHub interface.

If you have all your repositories cloned inside a single directory and you're on a UNIX-like operating system, you can use `grep` (or do all kinds of programmatic searches):

```
grep '"my-module": ' */package.json | grep -v '"\^5\.'
```

The above assumes that the entry starts with `^` and not `~` or a digit. Modify as needed. In your case, it's probably fine. If it isn't, it will show some version 5 instances, which is better than having it *not* show earlier instances.